# issue while getting values from Dictionary<int, List<int>>

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-2.0

I am having a dictionary which was defined as follows

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

I will have a list element where i can store the values which will come from database

```
List<int> lstdbTaskID = new List<int>();
```

assume this holds

```
100 105 110 200
```

respectively.

I will have my dictionary with values stored as follows. Assume that i have 2 keys 10,20 respectively, and for this key values i will have my values as for `10 i will have 100,105 and 110` `and for 20 i will have 200`.

I would like to compare these values with the list available `lstdbTaskID`

I tried this

```
foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
{
    if (dict1.ContainsValue(lstdbTaskID[strlst]))
}
```

But i am getting errors as follows

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>.ContainsValue(System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments`

and

> Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'`

can any help me on this?

Comment: What is the reason to stick with .NET 2.0 in late 2011??!

Comment: As my product is developed in that we have to stick to that

Comment: Please update your question that you are using .NET framework 2 otherwise users will keep posting LINQ queries, which anyhow will not solve your problem.. :).

Comment: @User: Your team definitely should consider the question to upgrade to 3.5 (minor testing required) or 4.0 (bit more testing required)

Comment: `abatishchev` yeah i too know that but what should i do as per the rules here we have to code in `2.0` frame work other wise we have to move the entire product to `3.0 or 4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong at because you are trying to compare `int` value with `List` of `int`.

Your dictionary is:
`Dictionary` of `int` to `List` of `int`.

and you have another structure as
`List` of `int`

so when you do:

```
// Compiler fails here because you are trying to check whether dictionary contains
// the given integer value. Dictionary in this case has a list of integers as its `Value` 
// in its `<Key,Value>` pair.
dict1.ContainsValue(lstdbTaskID[strlst])
```

Use linq statement:

```
foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
{
    if (dict1.Any(pair => pair.Value.Contains(strlst)))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Edit: If you want this without linq, do the linq task by self.

```
foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
{
    foreach (int key in dict1.Keys)
    {
        if (dict1[key].Contains(strlst))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already said i am not using linq as i am working on 2.0 frame work so can you give according to that

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type of the *value* you're storing in your dictionary - it's a `List<int>`, *not* an `int`. So it makes no sense to ask whether the dictionary contains a value of 5, say.

However, it does make sense to ask if the dictionary contains any value (list) which *itself* contains 5.

For example:

```
foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
{
    if (dict1.Values.Any(list => list.Contains(strlst))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, that's really not a very efficient way of representing it. It's not clear what the best of representing it *is* though, without knowing what you're going to do with the results. You may just want a `HashSet<int>` containing all the values from all the lists, for example - but if you want to get back to the keys whose values contained a particular ID, that's a different matter.

EDIT: In .NET 2.0 land, you could use:

```
foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
{
    foreach (List<int> list in dict1.Values)
    {
        if (list.Contains(strlst))
    }
}
```

... but you're really not using the dictionary *as* a dictionary in either case here...

Comment: @User: Okay, I've updated my answer - but it's not clear why you really want to be doing this. A dictionary is meant to provide fast key-to-value lookup; you're just using it as a list of lists here. Also note that in your sample you're using `lstdbTaskID[strlst]` where `strlst` is already an *otem* of `lstdbTaskID`, which sounds unlikely to be what you want to do. If you made your variable names less cryptic it may well help to make your question easier to understand...

Comment: Yeah the main code which i wrote is as per `PSJoshi` given, i will compare the key value and then the contains values then this is a dictionary case right

Answer (score 0):

I am having slight problems understanding your question fully, however, my answer should push you in the right direction. Seeing as you do not have access to Linq (as you are using .Net 2.0):

```
static bool IsContained(IEnumerable<int> lstdbTaskID, Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> dict1)
{
    foreach (int strlst in lstdbTaskID)
        foreach (HashSet<int> value in dict1.Values)
            if (value != null && value.Contains(strlst))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

You should use a `HashSet<int>` as it is far faster for looking up values (and is supported in .Net 2.0); however, you should not use `HashSet<int>` (and instead use `List<int>`) if:

- The list needs to store duplicates.
- - or - The order of the values is important.

Answer (score -1):

Well, dict1 is a dictionary of dictionaries, not ints.  So `dict1.ContainsValue` takes a dictionary as a parameter - you're checking whether it contains a given dictionary or not.  But you're giving it an `int`.

Try this:

```
if (dict1.Any(x => x.Value.ContainsValue(strlst))) // ...
```

Comment: can i have this with out `linq` as  
I am using 2.0 frame work